# Alias with Order by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query :

```
SELECT distinct(a0.ID,a0.str)  
from sev_modul_4_type1 as a0 
where ((lower(a0.str) LIKE '%а%'))
```

And i want to order it by str but if do it like that

```
select * from (
   SELECT distinct(a0.ID,a0.str)  
   from sev_modul_4_type1 as a0 
   where ((lower(a0.str) LIKE '%а%'))
) x order by str desc
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR:  column "str" does not exist
LINE 1: ...s a0 where ((lower(a0.str) LIKE '%а%'))) x order by str desc
                                                         ^
```

And even if i use `sev_modul_4_type1.str`, `a0.str` etc.

How can i do it right?

I also tried `order by 2 desc` but it gives me the same error and it's ok only `order by 1 desc` (which sorts by id)

Comment: `distinct` is ***NOT***  a function. `(a0.ID,a0.str)` is a **single** column with an anonymous row type. Remove those parentheses.

Comment: And what if i need to get a single column which contains both after sort ? f.e. `select distinct (a0.ID,
                a0.str)  from (
   SELECT *
   from sev_modul_4_type1 
   where ((lower(sev_modul_4_type1.str) LIKE '%а%'))
   order by str asc
) as a0 ` is breaking the sort

Comment: Why do you want a single column that contains two fields? And I have no idea what you mean with "breaking the sort". `distinct` is not a function. And unless you _really_ know what it means to return an anonymous record type with two fields in a single column you should never put parentheses around the column list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from (
   SELECT distinct a0.ID, a0.str  
   from sev_modul_4_type1 as a0 
   where ((lower(a0.str) LIKE '%а%'))
) x order by x.str desc
```

Try removing the parenthesis from distinct and then using the alias in your ORDER BY clause.

Comment: I see you also asked about returning distinct values to a single column. I don't know why you'd want to do this, but it can be achieved like this; 
`SELECT SINGLE_COLUMN
(SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255),a0.id) AS SINGLE_COLUMN
FROM sev_modul_4_type1 a0 WHERE a0.str LIKE '%a%'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255),a0.str) AS SINGLE_COLUMN
FROM sev_modul_4_type1 a0 WHERE a0.str LIKE '%a%') tbl
ORDER by tbl.SINGL_COLUMN ASC`

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
select * from (
   SELECT distinct a0.ID,
                a0.str  
   from sev_modul_4_type1 as a0 
   where ((lower(a0.str) LIKE '%а%'))
) x order by str desc
```